# error styling not showing when a select with multiple validates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I'm using jquery, bootstrap, and select2. When a field fails validation, it's border turns red. However, in the case of SELECT input types, it doesn't work when multiple is true. The validation still happens but isn't visually reflected, thus leaving the user confused as to which field needs filled out. (the actual form uses dozens of fields, this is just a dumbed down example)

I've googled quite a bit but haven't come across a definitive solution. I don't know why the error class would target the dropdown select component any differently between single and multiple selections.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Testing App</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/select2/select2.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap3.3.5/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/select2/select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/select2-bootstrap.css" />

<style>



        input.error, select.error,
        div.error a.select2-choice,
        textarea.error {
            border-color: red !important;
            color: red !important;
        }

        .select2.error {
            border-color: red !important;
            color: red !important;
        }


        span.error{
            outline: dotted;
            border: 1px solid #800000;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #800000;
          }
</style>



<script lang="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#thing').select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1});
        $('#stuff').select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1});

        $('#frmCreateEquipment').validate({
            ignore: [],
            rules : {
                thing : "required",
                stuff : "required",
            }
        });


        $('#send').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($('#frmCreateEquipment').valid()){
                console.log('ok');
            }else{
                console.log('fail');
            }
        });

    });


</script>

</head>



<body>    

<div class="container">
    <form id="frmCreateEquipment" action="javascript:void(0);">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="stuff" >Stuff:</label>
                <select id="stuff" name="stuff">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">aereae</option>
                    <option value="-1">Noy55yayne</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="thing" >Things:</label>
                <select id="thing" name="thing" multiple="multiple" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">fluid</option>
                    <option value="-1">None</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="send"name="send"type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I found this example which does make the multiple selection dropdowns work correctly, but then the dropdowns that don't use multiple no longer work...

http://jsfiddle.net/7nxw52jg/ (original)


http://jsfiddle.net/ak1hoq7u/  (forked example)

Comment: Just use the **EDIT** link under your post rather than putting critical additional information into the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a robust solution, but for having just one element to single out this'll works.  I apply the fix I found online to only the element that was giving me trouble, else I just use the original code from the validate plugin.

```
    $('#frmCreateEquipment').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules : {
            thing : "required",
            stuff : "required",
        },
        highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            if(element.id == "thing"){
                var e = $(element);
                if (e.hasClass('select2-offscreen')){
                    $('#s2id_'+e.attr('id')+' ul').addClass(errorClass);
                }
            }else{
                if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
                    this.findByName( element.name ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
                } else {
                    $( element ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
                }
            }
        },

    });
```

Comment: When using `highlight`, you should have a corresponding complimentary function within `unhighlight` that does the opposite.  Otherwise, you cannot clear the errors.

Comment: Oh I do, I just didn't bother including it here because it's essentially the same code.

Comment: The whole point of SO is to maintain this repository to help others.  What if somebody comes here to use your answer and does not have any idea about `unhighlight`?